# text-align justify not working

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I'm trying to justify the text within this p tag so that it perfectly fits the width of the p.

```
<p align="justify" style="text-align: justify !important; color:#fff; margin:0px; font-weight:bold; width:487px; border:Solid 1px red;">blah blah blah</p>
```

but the text just wont justify! any idea why?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 42):

You can use the solution described here:
http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/css/css-one-line-justify.html

This will justify a single line but adds a space after, so if you know the height, you can specify it with `overflow:hidden` to conceal it and still get the justification.

```css
.fulljustify {
     text-align:justify;
    }
    .fulljustify:after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%; 
    }
    #tagline {
        height: 80px;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 80px; /* vert-center */
    }
```

```html
<p id="tagline" class="fulljustify">Blah blah blah</p>
```

Comment: For a single line, this

Comment: this doesn't work in IE8 and FF lower versions. do you know some way to implement without using `:after` pseudo code and `content`? thanks

Answer (score 38):

If your text doesn't span more than one line, justifying doesn't do anything. Your text has to wrap to the next line, and then the FIRST line will be justified, but not the second.

Comment: darn. so theres no css way to justify 4 words in a 487 width p?

Comment: is correct.  You also needed to change the `color` from white on a white background to see this.  http://jsfiddle.net/5RpQr/

Comment: @jason gennaro - yeah, i spent a minute trying to figure out why i didn't see anything in the fiddle... haha

Comment: .haha

@phil, see my answer for a possible other solution re justifying four words

Comment: Wow, that's really confusing, e.g. when in ckeditor setting the first line to justify, you won't see any changes. I wasted an hour figuring that out, thinking the plugin was broken. Hah!

Answer (score 14):

Chrome doesn't support it but in Firefox and IE, you can use `text-align-last: justify;`. For a cross-browser solution, we have to use what @onemanarmy posted ;)

Comment: As of Dec 2016, this is now supported in all major browsers (65%) and is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, this is now the best (and simplest) solution.Works great in chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari. It's the default browser on OS X, so I'd consider it a major browser.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Works in chrome too. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted to justify four words in `487px` you could try using `word-spacing` in your `css`.

I used `word-spacing:8em;` for `bla bla bla bla` but you could adjust as necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/5RpQr/1/

Comment: @phil - Just remember that if you change your words, the word spacing must change too

Answer (score 7):

try this

for div

```
div {
text-align:justify;
text-justify: inter-word;
text-align-last:center;
/* for IE9 */
-ms-text-align-last:center;
}
```

Comment: thanks, you saved my bacon. I love how these CSS styles were created without any planning, by pushing it forward with the belly.

Answer (score 0):

There is also something similar, like display: flex; justify-content: space-around; if you would wrap those texts in spans or divs

Answer (score 0):

In my case for < p > tag, works with easy way:

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-justify/

Answer (score 0):

To make it look good on Chrome & opera (multiline justify looks bad on them)

I use the following

```
.fulljustify {
  text-align: justify;
  display: table-row;
  text-align-last: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome solution:
If you don't want to mess with the display properties (in my case aligning an anchor tag of a carousel img):

`text-align: -webkit-center;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me this way:

```
<div className={s.element}> {text} </div>

.element {
  text-align:justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You better try

```css
style="text-align:justifty;display:inline-block;"
```

Answer (score -6):

Just use `style="text-align:justify"`.
It works in all browsers.

Comment: some kind of explanation would be helpful, won't it? he obiviously used your styles...

Comment: @Ron If you want to justify whole paragraph except last row use above trick, and if you want to justify last line also then use ` .justify:after{content: ""; display: inline-block; width: 100%;}` and no need to define height.

Comment: he already use the inline css with `text-align: justify` , Please reconsider to give op solution.