# text-align: justify isn't stretching to the width of the div

Tags: html, css, text-align, text-justify

My code:

```
<div style="width: 400px; text-align: justify; background: yellow">hello world hello world</div>
```

I'd expect that to stretch "hello world hello world" to 400px, making the spacing between each word as large as necessary. Except that it isn't and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Example on jsiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xq9ktn9/

Comment: That looks somewhat helpful but...  the accepted answer from 2011 has a link to a jquery plugin that now redirects to the jquery homepage. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/charjustify

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228347/text-align-justify-not-working